# Can I change a little the existing question to a new one?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have previously asked an obvious question and got no answer but very helpful comments which answer me. I find that if I change a little, qualification of question and may be answers will grow up.

Two issues:

1. But if I do this later comments will be silly.
2. Existing question is favorite!!! for one member.

Which should I do: New question or change old bad question?

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834601/is-there-a-method-to-list-all-periodic-points-for-a-funcion)?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes I want to ask for "method which determine functions have at least one periodic" instead.